# how to extract a value from xml document in postgresql

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, xml-parsing

How to extract the value of `clientid` from the following xml document in Postgres?

I want to get value `1435` from this xml:

```
CREATE TABLE xmltest3(xtxt xml);
INSERT INTO xmltest3 values ('<clients><client clientId="1435"/></clients>');
SELECT unnest(xpath('./client /text()', xtxt::xml))::text AS XMLDATA FROM XMLTEST3;
```

I tried:

```
SELECT unnest(xpath('./clients/text()', xtxt::xml))::text AS XMLDATA 
FROM XMLTEST3;
```

But it is not working.

Also, how to extract the `ENvalues` from this?

```
<ENList><EN ENValue="Liquidity"/><EN ENValue="Treasury"/></ENList>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@clientId` to get the attribute value:

```
with invar as (
  select '<clients><client clientId="1435"/></clients>'::xml as x
) 

select unnest(xpath('/clients/client/@clientId', x))
  from invar;
 unnest 
--------
 1435
(1 row)
```

The concept is the same for your other example:

```
with invar as (
  select '<ENList><EN ENValue="Liquidity"/><EN ENValue="Treasury"/></ENList>'::xml as x
) 
select unnest(xpath('/ENList/EN/@ENValue', x))
  from invar;

  unnest   
-----------
 Liquidity
 Treasury
(2 rows)
```